# Hibernate Event Listeners not called after using Merging Persistence Unit Manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i have a component which was developed and added as a dependency to our project... i need to use the entity specified in that component and inorder to do that i had to use the MergingPersistenceUnitManager from the Spring data-jpa project. 
This component defines a persistence.xml which has the unitName same as the parent project in which it is used.
Now, i have two persistence.xml files and both are loaded during the EntityManagerFactory creation using the MergingPersistenceUnitManager.

Everything works fine and the Entity is loaded and detected during container startup... 
However the problem that i face here is, that my declared hibernate listeners arent called at all.. They never seem to be invoked, and i have verified that they work if i remove the component and have only one persistence.xml file.

```
<persistence-unit name="LineManagement" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"     />
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"     value="thread" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="1000" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="/ehcache.xml" />

            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-update" value="com......dao.listener.ChangeHistoryMultiSelectListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-insert" value="com......dao.listener.LMCoreEntityAuditListener" />

        <!-- General Debugging -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

The second persistence.xml is just this

```
    <persistence-unit name="LineManagement" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    </persistence-unit>
```

I realised that after i started using the MergingPersistenceUnitManager my listeners are never called... 
Here is a snippet from one of them.

```
public class LMCoreEntityAuditListener
      implements PreInsertEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener, Initializable {
   private static final String MODIFIED_BY = "modifiedBy";
   private static final String CREATED_BY = "createdBy";

   @Override
   public boolean onPreInsert(final PreInsertEvent event) {
      System.out.println("ssss");
      if (!(event.getEntity() instanceof LMBaseEntity)) {
         return false;
      }
      final LMBaseEntity entity = (LMBaseEntity) event.getEntity();
      if (!(entity instanceof GlobalLine) || (entity.getCreatedTimestamp() == null)) {
         // auditCreates(entity);
         final String user = SecurityContextUtil.getOriginalUser();
         final List<String> props = Arrays.asList(event.getPersister().getPropertyNames());
         event.getState()[props.indexOf(CREATED_BY)] = user;
         event.getState()[props.indexOf(MODIFIED_BY)] = user;
      }

      return false;
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe i am missing something basic. The dependencies are properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The MergingPersistenceUnitManager from spring data is not merging the properties.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/support/MergingPersistenceUnitManager.java

Compare it to following example of a merging unit manager which includes the properties.

https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Multiple+persistence.xml+in+a+multi-module+application

Comment: Good observation! Would you mind opening a JIRA to add this for completeness? Thanks!